# How can i add embedded resources to dll during build process

Tags: c#, build-process

I have a flavored c# project and package
i can catch the **buildbegin event** when the dll is building 
what i want is to embedding some files into the building dll in this event handler

how can i fullfill this task 
can i just add these files to project file but not displayed in the solution tree?

Comment: Why you want to do this?  Is there some reason why you don't want to use embedded resources?

Comment: cause i allow user add new item to my project
and i want zip that added item as a resource to the dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Assembly Linker tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx)

```
al.exe MyLib.module /out:MyLib.dll /embed:MyRes.txt
```

Comment: but how can i add these programmingly ?
is there exist some property in the project that i can change?
great thanks

Comment: You can add to the project and set file property to embeded resource, but as I guess you don't like it, in the other side you can create a batch file, or call al.exe tool by Process class programitically

Comment: it seems to be a probelem
what i want to embeded to is a dll not a module
how can i do that?

Comment: for dll you can build your code by csc.exe with /resource option, but I don't think it is better than adding file to solution tree

Comment: finally i put a fragment in the project files,with the "*.xml" to embed multiple files..